# displaying/adding to/removing from a list of items in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Users on my site can have any number of email addresses linked to their account. I'm making a page to do this. On page load, all the email addresses associated with a user are pulled from the database and displayed on the page. Then, the user should be able to add, edit and remove these emails.

Lots of websites need to do this, so I thought there might be existing tools that provide this functionality. Do any of the existing Controls do something like this?

I looked through the documentation, but there are lots of controls and it is hard to tell what it is possible to do with them.

I could make my own implementation, but I hate to reinvent the wheel (and it feels like this is something people should need to do all the time.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridView` control will let you do this, although it's a bit of overkill considering you have such simple requirements. In the `GridView`, you'd have to specify a `DataSource`, and then listen for the `RowEditing`, `RowUpdating`, `RowCancelingEdit`, and `RowDeleting` events, update your `DataSource` appropriately inside each event, and saving to the database when you deem it's necessary. There's a fairly good overview of this [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx).

I say "when you deem it's necessary" because some people save after every action, but others (like me) prefer to provide users with "Save" and "Reset" buttons so that they can back out their modifications without actually changing anything in the database. This level of oversight is probably not necessary for your list of e-mail addresses, however.

Frankly, though, I'd just provide users with an HTML text box, an add button, and a save button, looking something like:

```
New E-mail address: <input type="text" id="newEmail" /> <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
Current E-mail addresses:
user@host.domain <input type="checkbox" id="database-Id-goes-here" /> Delete?
user2@host.domain <input type="checkbox" id="database-Id-goes-here" /> Delete?
...
```

You could easily make this server-side by just adding the `runat="server"` attribute to these controls. The "Current E-mail addresses" section would fit nicely inside a `Repeater` control.

You could write JavaScript code to handle saving this data, but unless you have a lot of other stuff on this page (which would complicate your page lifecycle and force you to handle lots of `if (Page.IsPostBack == false)` conditions), I would stick to the server-side implementation.

**To address your final concern about reinventing the wheel:** personally, I prefer reinventing the wheel in these situations. The built-in Microsoft controls can handle a lot of these CRUD-style pages, but unless you need to represent complex data (and thus a complex life-cycle), it'll be just as easy to implement this on your own.

It's unlikely that your users are going to need to edit or update multiple e-mail addresses at once, and your validation is going to be minimalistic (compared to validating a larger object), so I wouldn't try to find a Microsoft control that fits your needs here.

In addition to that, it's likely that a `Repeater` and straight HTML will be much faster, too. Your users may not notice the difference because the binding will be short regardless, but it doesn't hurt to keep these considerations in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll try out the GridView control - I didn't know that it was possible to do those kinds of things with that control, so its good to know for when I need to make more complex things. As you say though, I may just do the simple HTML solution.

Answer (score 1):

2 Different approaches

**1)SERVER SIDE** :   In the "Add" button event, Create a textbox object in your codebehind, and add that to the form. Then in your save button click, read from that too.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx

**2)CLIENT SIDE** : Using java script (go for jquery to make it easy) add an input text element to the form and in your submit button click (hope its a save using ajax).

http://jsfiddle.net/u9hvp/

the links are some samples which is similar (adding a label control from codebehind and adding a texbox using javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Listview and objectdatasource. Gridview does inline editing, has poor rendering, has no inbuilt insert capabilities.